# Automatic Created by column

Tags: user

I have list, in that when user enter a new item i should have a column called name and it should populate the current user name who creating the entry automatically. No need to enter Name separately.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question, that column already exists in all SharePoint lists! It's the `Author` column (aka field), and it is displayed as `Created by` for all items.

You can rename it if you want: on a given list, click on the `List` tab, then choose `List settings`. on the new `List settings` page, scroll down to find the column `Created by` (under the section `columns`). Click on it: on the new page, you can rename it.

Also, you can make it appear on the default view of your list by editing the view (go to the list, `List` tab, `Edit view` button).

Answer (score 0):

You get this for free on every list or library. The Created By field is populated with the person who submits the item. It will then appear in the footer of the View form. It doesn't appear on the New form, but it can be added to the view so you can see it.